# Update Info (from SVN) shows "Nothing to show" when "Group by Changelist" is enabled

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

**Preamble :)**

I'm working on a project which is versioned in SVN. I've set up an *initial* IntelliJ workspace on the trunk version and since then I'm copying the `.idea` folder and the respective `.iml` files to every *branch* I'm working on, in order to aviod configuring application servers, artifacts, etc. anew every time.
I've found that by doing this, all of the settings of the initial project workspace are copied without any significant side effects... Except for one, that I can't seem to figure out:

**The issue**

When updating from SVN, the very useful tab "Update Info" shows up in the Version Control tool window. When the button "Group by Changelist" is off, the  window shows the changed files since the last update.

[image]

Alternatively, when the button "Group by Changelist" is on, the  window splits in 2, showing a) the changed revisions since the last update on the left and b) the changed files per revision on the right. Well, that's how it should be, but in my case, it shows "Nothing to show"/"No Differences":

[image]

**Note** that in the original workspace (see preamble) this is not happening and the changed revisions/changelists are showing up just fine.

I've tried "Cleanup", every type of "Refresh" in the Version Control window, but the issue does not get fixed.
I also tried to go through the `workspace.xml` file, deleted the `<component name="ChangeListManager">` contents which refreshed the Version Control window completely, but still no joy.

Anyone with a similar issue who may have found a workaround for this?

IDEA version is 2016.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a wild guess - you have a whitespace or some other special character in the repository URL of branches where it does not work. And it is IntelliJ bug.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78174